# Simple for loops, simple arrays, utterly baffling output

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have what I thought to be a very simple nested loop to fill a 2d array (the point being to fill a table with values, conditionally). The results are more than unexpected, and I cannot see or find my mistake.

I don't get why all arrays are filled (table[0] and[1] should be empty, the loops only start at 2) and why all are filled with the same.
A console.log in the inner if did show that that part of code only runs when it should and produces the expected output, which means that the assignment only happens with those, verified as correct, values. Yet before the inner loop for R+1 is even started, table[R+1] is already filled, with the content of table[R].

Basically (console.log debugged) the erroneously filled fields are never assigned to by my code, yet are filled. Also overwriting other values.

Observed in Node.js and Chrome console, didn't try other runtimes.

Code:

```
const table = (new Array(7)).fill(new Array(7));
for (let R = 2; R <= 6; R++) {
  for (let N = 2; N <= 6; N++) {
    if (R + N <= 8) {
      table[R][N] = '' + R + N;
    }
  }
}
```

expected result:

```
[
[ , , , , , , ],
[ , , , , , , ],
[ , , '22', '23', '24', '25', '26' ],
[ , , '32', '33', '34', '35', ],
[ , , '42', '43', '44', , ],
[ , , '52', '53', , , ],
[ , , '62', , , , ]
]
```

Actual result:

```
[
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
[ , , '62', '53', '44', '35', '26' ],
]
```

Comment: Please post initialization and definition of the array referred to by `table`.

Comment: Was a formatting error, it's there now. ```const table = (new Array(7)).fill(new Array(7))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was an idiot and should have RTFM.
If Array.fill() gets passed an Object, it stores the Reference.

Comment: I can't click accept on this answer, some mod feel free to.

Comment: Yes, what you pass to `Array.prototype.fill` becomes the value of every array element. With primitive values like number literals (`1`, `2` etc) that works as expected by most without understanding how JavaScript memory model works, but with objects the values are references, meaning that when passing an object to the `fill` function, every array element references that object. Basically, every element of your `table` array was the array created *once*, with `new Array(7)` when passed to `fill`.

Comment: You can accept the answer later as you gain more reputation on the site. I can't accept it for you either.